# Количество столбцов при использовании UNION

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Делаю две выборки через `UNION` где первая это выбрать все записи за период и втораю вывести в конце списка сумму выбраного. Проблема в том что некоторые столбцы, такие как время и т.д., мне не нужны и когда я исключаю их с второй выборки то база выдает: `SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns`. Как игнорировать сумму некоторых столбцов?
Рабочий код, который суммирует все:

```
            "SELECT %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 " FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q = %q AND %q BETWEEN '%q-%q-%q' AND '%q-%q-%q'"
            " UNION ALL "
            "SELECT SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", TOTAL(%q)"
                 ", TOTAL(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", TOTAL(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 ", SUM(%q)"
                 "FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q = %q AND %q BETWEEN '%q-%q-%q' AND '%q-%q-%q';"
```

Comment: При UNION количество столбцов должно быть одинаковым. Как вариант - использовать заглушки вида "", а затем все еще раз обернуть SELECT * FROM (Select ...) as zxc where условие

Comment: поставьте на место не существующих столбцов NULL что бы количество совпадало

Comment: И кстати, не могу понять, зачем вы так усложняете себе жизнь, подставляя названия полей как параметры, а не пишите названия прямо в запросе. Я могу еще представить, что у вас изменится имя таблицы, префиксы распространенная вещь. Но что бы переименовывались колонки, это как то уже перебор. Если уж колонки вдруг переименовывают, то обычно и логику работы с БД при этом меняют и запросы все равно придется переделывать

Comment: @Mike, запросов много, заметил что допускаю много ошибок если писать все в запрос, да и структура временная.

Comment: Хм. лично я бы точно запутался и допускал много ошибок, если бы постоянно считал в каком порядке надо перечислить колонки отдельно от запроса. И временной структуры БД не бывает. Если меняется структура, то те части приложения, что работали с БД просто выбрасываются и переписываются заново. Поэтому 95% структуры БД проектируется до написания первой строки кода (кроме тестов производительности при проектировании) и после этого уже не меняется.